# Why does my Excel Chart have two X Axis points where they don't exist in the data

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a table which is used to build a chart. My table contains date values for weekdays. The chart I generate from the data includes weekend dates automatically even though the dates are not present in my table.

Why are weekend dates automatically included in my chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some types of Excel charts acknowledge timelines on the X axis. If the data for the X axis is date based, Excel will try to plot them as a time line, i.e. if days are missing in the data, they will show as empty data points.

You can format the axis and change the axis properties to display the data as categories instead.

In the screenshot, the top chart's X axis is formatted as a date axis. Days with no data don't have a column.

The other chart uses the "text" as the axis type and it plots only the available data points as categories.

[image]

Comment: Do you by chance know how I could change this setting with EPPlus?